# Определить длину слова в пикселях

Tags: php

Есть таблица, в ячейках которых не должно быть переносов. Поэтому слишком длинные фразы в ячейках хочу обрезать. Проблема в том, что слова "ММММММММММММ" и "гггггггггггг", оба состоящие из 12 символов, имеют разную ширину. Значит надо как-то посчитать ширину слова в пикселях.

### Вариант первый ##

Разделяем фразу на символы.
У каждого отдельного символа мы знаем ширину
суммируем все значения, вот и результат.

### Вариант второй

Использовать `imagettfbbox()`

### Вариант третий

Засунуть весь текст в `<samp> </samp>`

Проблема в том, что первый способ ресурсоёмкий, второй требует подключения шрифта, третий  уродует текст. Есть ещё идеи?

Comment: А вы в курсе, что количество пикселей на экране бывает разным у разных устройств? Если известно, что определенная буква шире, чем эталонная, то почему бы просто не фильтровать через условие? То есть если М шире скажем в 2 раза, то минус 1 из максимальной длины слова.

Comment: @Lucky, нет, над этим пока даже не задумывался... И что же мне теперь делать?(

Comment: буквально три минуты назад прочитал, что overflow: hidden; и table-layout: fixed; решат все мои проблемы

Comment: Лучше text-overflow: ellipsis в сочетании с white-space: nowrap; В любом случае, советую почитать статью по ссылке сверху.

Comment: Можете оформить это ответом, чтобы я принял?

Comment: Оформил ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В CSS есть встроенные решения для обрезки контента, выходящего за рамки родительского блока. Вам нужен [`text-overflow`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-overflow)